# How to get the connection information about the running jupyter notebook editor of vscode from another extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently developing a vscode extension that is activated when a notebook editor is open. The extension needs to get some connection information about the notebook so that I could use the jupyter_client module. Is there any APIs that could be useful? For example, is it possible that the extension creates a notebook cell with "%connect_info" magic command and accesses the cell's output to get some information about the running notebook?